# How to use selector with xamarin radiobutton to set background colors?

Tags: xamarin, radio-button, selector

I have two radio buttons, which looks like a normal buttons. I would like to change their background color by using radio_button.xml with selector inside.
If I use little .png image to set background then it works fine.
But I tried similar code to use just colors (integers) and it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Code with background image:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:id="@+id/radioLeft"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button"
        android:checked="true" />
    <RadioButton
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:id="@+id/radioRight"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button" />
</RadioGroup>
```

radio_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/gray_dot" />
  <item android:state_checked="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/blue_dot" />
</selector>
```

button_colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="button_black">#000000</color>
  <color name="button_white">#ffffff</color>
  <color name="button_blue">#00afdb</color>
  <color name="button_gray">#dcdcdc</color>
</resources>
```

I tried to replace

```
android:drawable="@drawable/blue_dot"
```

with

```
android:background="@color/button_blue"
```

but it's not working. How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used shape xml with color to avoid background images.

radio_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/rb_checked" />
  <item android:state_checked="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/rb_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

rb_checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="@color/button_blue" />
</shape>
```

Main.axml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:id="@+id/radioLeft"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <RadioButton
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:id="@+id/radioRight"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RadioGroup>
```

[image: Buttons in the cell phone emulator:]

Answer (score 0):

The trick that worked for me was

```
radioLeft.ButtonDrawable.SetTint(GetColor(Resource.Color.button_blue));
```

Or whatever color you wish to set, depending on the checked state, eg

```
radioLeft.ButtonDrawable.SetTint(GetColor(radioLeft.Checked ? Resource.Color.button_blue : Resource.Color.button_gray));
```